# Convert undstructured blocks of data in a columnwise manner (DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Description of the problem:

I have an external *.xls file that I have converted to a *.csv file containing block of data such as:

```
"Legend number one";;;;Number of items;6
X;-358.6806792;-358.6716338;;;
Y;0.8767189;0.8966855;Avg;;50.1206378
Z;-0.7694626;-0.7520983;Std;;-0.0010354
D;8.0153902;8;Err;;1.010385
;;;;;
```

There is many many blocks.

Each block may contain some additional lines data;

```
"Legend number six";;;;Number of items;19
X;-358.6806792;-358.6716338;;;
Y;0.8767189;0.8966855;Avg;;50.1206378
Z;-0.7654644;-0.75283;Std;;-0.0010354
D;8.0153902;8;Err;;1.010385
A;0;1;Value;;0
B;1;0;;;
;;;;;
```

The structure is such that a new empty line separate each blocs, which is the ';;;;;;' line in my samples.

The first line after this begins with a unique identifier of the block.

It appears that each line contains 6 elements such as `key1;elem1;elem2;key2;elem3;elem4` which would be nice to represent as two 3-elements vector `key1;elem1;elem2` and `key2;elem3;elem4` on two separate lines. Example for the second sample:

```
"Legend number six";;
;;Number of items;19
X;-358.6806792;-358.6716338;
;;
Y;0.8767189;0.8966855;
Avg;;50.1206378
Z;-0.7654644;-0.75283;
Std;;-0.0010354
D;8.0153902;8;
Err;;1.010385
A;0;1;
Value;;0
B;1;0;
;;
;;;;;
```

Some are empty but I do not want to discard them for the moment.
But I would like to end up a DataFrame containing columnwise elements for each block of data.

### The cleanest "pre solution" I have so far:

With this Python code I ended up in a more organized "List of dictionaries":

```
import os, sys, re, glob
import pandas as pd
csvFile = os.path.join(workingDir,'file.csv')
h = 0 # Number of lines to skip in head
s = 2 # number of values per key
s += 1
str1 = 'Number of items' 

# Reading file in a global list and storing each line in a sublist:
A = [line.split(';') for line in open(csvFile).read().split('\n')]
# This code splits each 6-elements sublist in one new sublist 
# containing two-elements; each element with 3 values:
B = [(';'.join(el[:s])+'\n'+';'.join(el[s:])).split('\n') for el in A] 

# Init empty structures:
names = [] # to store block unique identifier (the name in the legend)
L = [] # future list of dictionnaries

for el in (B):
    for idx,elj in enumerate(el):
        vi = elj.split(';')[1:]
        # Here we grep the name only when the 2nd element of 
        # the first line contains the string "Number of items", 
        # which is constant all over the file:
        if len(vi)>1 and vi[0]==str1:
            name = el[idx-1].split(';')[0]
            names.append(name)
            #print(name)

# We loop again over B to append in a new list one dictionary 
# per vector of 3 elements because each vector of 3 elements 
 # is structured like ; key;elem1;elem2          
for el in (B):
    for elj in (el):
        k = elj.split(';')[0]
        v = elj.split(';')[1:]
        # Little tweak because the key2;elem3;elem4 of the 
        # first line (the one containing the name) have the 
        # key in the second place like "elem3;key2;elem4" :
        if len(v)>1 and v[0]==str1:            
            kp = v[0]
            v = [v[1],k]
            k = kp
        if k!='':
            dct = {k:v}
            L.append(dct)
```

I am unsuccessful to extract the name as a global identifier and all values of the blocs as variable so far. I can't play with some modulo based technique because of the variable number of informations in each separate block of data even if all block contain at least some common keys.
I also tried a `while` condition within a `for` loop all over each dictionary but it's a mess now.
`zip` could potentially be a nice option but I don't really know how to use it properly.

### Target DataFrame:

What I'd like to end up should ideally look something similar to a DataFrame containing;

```
index                'Number of items'    'X'    ''  'Y'  'Avg'  'Z'   'Std' ...
"Legend number one"    6                  ...
"Legend number six"   19                  ...
"Legend number 11"     6                  ...
"Legend number 15"    18                  ...
```

The columns names are the keys and the table is containing the values for each block of data on a separate line.
If there is a numbered index and a new column with "Legend name"; it's OK as well.

### CSV sample to play with:

```
"Legend number one";;;;Number of items;6
X;8.6806792;8.6716338;;;
Y;0.1557;0.1556;Avg;;50.1206378
Z;-0.7859;-0.7860;Std;;-0.0010354
D;8.0153902;8;Err;;1.010385
;;;;;
"Legend number six";;;;Number of items;19
X;56.6806792;56.6716338;;;
Y;0.1324;0.1322;Avg;;50.1206378
Z;-0.7654644;-0.75283;Std;;-0.0010354
D;8.0153902;8;Err;;1.010385
A;0;1;Value;;0
B;1;0;;;
;;;;;
"Legend number 11";;;;Number of items;6
X;358.6806792;358.6716338;;;
Y;0.1324;0.1322;Avg;;50.1206378
Z;-0.7777;-0.7778;Std;;-0.0010354
D;8.0153902;8;Err;;1.010385
;;;;;
"Legend number 15";;;;Number of items;18
X;58.6806792;58.6716338;;;
Y;0.1324;0.1322;Avg;;50.1206378
Z;0.5555;0.5554;Std;;-0.0010354
D;8.0153902;8;Err;;1.010385
A;0;1;Value;;0
B;1;0;;;
C;0;0;k;1;0
;;;;;
```

I'm using Ubuntu and Python 3.6 but the script must work on a Windows computer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Appending this to the previous code should work pretty well:

```
for elem in L:
    for key,val in elem.items():
        if key in names:
            name = key
            Dict2 = {}
        else:
            Dict2[key] = val
        Dict1[name] = Dict2

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dict1, orient='index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index)
for col in df1.columns:
    colS = df1[col].apply(pd.Series)
    colS = colS.rename(columns = lambda x : col+'_'+ str(x))
    df2 = pd.concat([df2[:], colS[:]], axis=1)

df2.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', index=True, header=True)
```

There is probably many other ways to go...

This link was helpful:
https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_expand_cells_containing_lists/

Comment: It's annoying ; *I almost always find an answer on my own a few moments after having officially searched for help online, even if it has been for days I was stuck!*